# Is it possible to set the value of a DataGridRow cell for new rows?

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, xaml, datagridview

I am very new to WPF and XAML so I may be going about this the wrong way.

I have a DataGrid that is bound to a data source using the Entity Framework.

When I add a new row to the DataGrid, I'd like to have one of the columns named "Created" automatically populate with the current date and time.

The data ultimately ends up on a SQL Server.

The "Created" column on the SQL server is not nullable, but does have a default value of "getdate()." It's been working fine with our current MS Access application. When running manual insert queries, simply leaving out a value for the "Created" column triggers the default value.

A new row uses the default value of "1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM" instead of the current date and time, despite the SQL server's default value being "getdate()."

I've tried:

- Changing the Model so that the column's default value wasn't "(None)" but was "DateTime.Now," I also tried just "Now." Neither worked.
- Changing the Model so that the column's nullable property was true.
- I tried the DataGridView's "AddingNewItem" event, but couldn't get it to work.
- I tried the DataGridView's "RowEditEnding" event, but couldn't figure out how to get it to work either.
- I tried completely removing the column in question from the DataGridView but when calling SaveChanges() on the dbContext object, it throws an exception saying the conversion of datetime2 to datetime caused an out of range exception or something along those lines. The exact error is (The first exception is "UpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details."): [image: Error]

I'm not sure how to do this. I know that the "View" is only supposed to be responsible for presenting the data, but I'm not sure how to change the Model so that new rows for this particular table either don't send a value for the "Created" column or always pass the current date and time when adding a new row.

I've spent hours looking at WPF documentation, Entity Framework documentation, Stack Overflow, MSDN Documentation... I'm about to pull my hair out! Any help would be greatly, GREATLY appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm pretty sure the DataGrid.AddingNewItem event is the one you want. Try something like this:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Collection}" 
          CanUserAddRows="True"
          AddingNewItem="DataGrid_AddingNewItem">
```

And then in your code-behind:

```
private void DataGrid_AddingNewItem(object sender, AddingNewItemEventArgs e)
{
    e.NewItem = new Model
    {
        Created = DateTime.Now //whatever you put here will be the default value
    };
}
```